# Keep URL query string attached when navigating pages

Tags: string, navigation, web

okay, so I add ?LeadSourceId=777 to end of links from paid advertising such as facebook. This is picked up by any of our infusionsoft web forms and tells us the user has originated from facebook. problem is with '?LeadSourceId=777' on the end of the link it only stays there whilst you view that page.

If I click a link on that page and go to somewhere else in the website the link loses the leadsourceid string.

Is there any way to keep that string on the end of the URLs as someone navigates through all the pages on the website in one single session?

Answer (score 0):

Use a backed scripting language.

In PHP I'd just store the LeadSourceId variable in the session and pull it out every time I need it.

Comment: Thanks, but if I was going to store the string I would prefer to do so with cookies and set it to 100 days or so. That way I can keep an originating lead source active even if they decide to come back to site a week later.

Any way to do this?

Comment: you'd have to use javascript but you'd loose the functionality if javascript was disabled. PHP sessions use cookies to store the session token so they offer the same functionality as cookies i.e. you can set the expiry date to whatever you want, but you can store a lot more and as they are handled server side they are more secure. If you wan tto use Javascript to store the cookies look here: http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/